# What is the CORRECT string function for LEFT in sqldf python?

Tags: python, sqldf, pandasql

Building SQL code in Python platform using 'from pandasql import sqldf'.
Trying to perform LEFT function as follow but to no avail.
Tried with LEFTSTR function as well. No such function found. Anyone come across it?

```
query2="""
SELECT Name, LEFT(Name,2)
FROM df
"""
```